# Python : How add a datepicker in .kv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

Can anyone tell me how to add a `date picker` or kivy calendar on `date` TextBox?
I have two file `test.py` and `test.kv` file.

## test.py

```
import kivy
import sqlite3 as lite

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.label import Label


Window.clearcolor = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1)
Window.size = (400, 125)


class Testing(Screen):
    pass

class Testing(App):

    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file('test.kv')
        return self.root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Testing().run()
```

## test.kv

```
Testing:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        padding : 20, 20

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            padding: 10, 10
            spacing: 10, 10
            size_hint_x: .55

            Label:
                text: "Date"
                text_size: self.size
                valign: 'middle'
                size_hint_x: .2

            TextInput:
                size_hint_x: .3

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            padding : 10, 0
            spacing: 10, 10
            size_hint: .5, .7
            pos_hint: {'x': .25, 'y':.25}

            Button:
                text: 'Ok'
                on_release:
                    root.dismiss()

            Button:
                text: 'Cancel'
                on_release: root.dismiss()
```

Answer (score 0):

> .kv file

```
#:import MDTextField kivymd.uix.textfield.MDTextField
MDTextField:
    id: set_date
    hint_text: 'Start Date'
    write_tab: False
    on_focus: root.setDate()
```

> .py file

```
from kivymd.uix.picker import MDDatePicker
def setDate(self,dobj):
    self.ids.set_date.text = str(dobj)
    pass

def fromDate(self):
    self.foc = self.ids.set_date.focus
    if(self.foc==True):
        MDDatePicker(self.setFDate).open()
    else:
        print("not")
```